# xamarin forms navigation in 2.5 xamarin.forms version

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just updated both the xamarin forms version on my visual studio project and Visual studio. My existing project started to throw an error after the update. Since it was a small project. I decided to rewrite the application again. In my earlier application in my MainPage.xaml, I had the following code on the click of the button

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new gridpage());
```

and in my gridPage(), I had the following code on the click of the test button

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new testpage());
```

now in new Xamarin.forms when i am trying to create a page, i am only getting either xaml page or .cs page. I am not getting both xaml and cs page. The options to create a new page are:

```
ContentPage.xaml
ContentPage(c#)
ContentView
Content View C#
ListView
MasterDetail
Tabbed and Viewcell
```

Do I need create two pages separately like Testpage.xaml and testpage.cs? to accomplish the same navigation. I need both code behind page and xaml page.

Thank You.

Comment: What is the error when you open your older Xamarin project? Could you please post the complete error message? And what are you mean "not getting both `.xaml` and `.cs` page"? Do you mean "`.xaml` and `.xaml.cs` file"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the "Forms Xaml Page" Templeate by right click on Project>Add New item>Forms Xaml Page template.

Then you will able to see both xaml & .cs files.